# android-jetpack-compose after click button I want to disable button for some time and enable it again

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

like title said, I need after click to disable button for some time, so it will not be clickable, and when that time expired to enable again button so it can be clickable.

```
    Button(
      onClick = {},
      modifier = //maybe to add code here?
    ) {
        Text(text = "Click me")
      }
```

It would be great if code can be added to Modifier, that would be great! Because then it would been reusable and used not just for Button, and for others components too.

Comment: you definitevely need a variable that stores whether the button is enabled / disabled, then inside of "onClick" just change the variable value to false and launch a side-effect with a delay to re-enable it (see: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) // will post a code answer later, if nobody does it first

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one way of achieving this with `delay`:

```kotlin
    var enabled by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    LaunchedEffect(enabled) {
        if (enabled) return@LaunchedEffect
        else delay(1000L)
        enabled = true
    }

    Button(
        onClick = { enabled = false }, 
        enabled = enabled
    ) {
        Text(text = "Click Me")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

var clickEnabled by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

Button(modifier = Modifier.clickable(enabled = clickEnabled) {
                            clickEnabled = false
                            scope.launch {
                                delay(1000)
                                clickEnabled = true
                            }
                        })
```